# How to run test with local.example.js ENV

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, mocha.js, superagent

I have 2 env:

- dev
- local.example.js
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uENja.png)

i run test with this command "mocha specs/* --opts ./mocha.opts" and default run dev ENV.
What command I can use for a run with local.example.js ENV ?

Like "mocha specs/* --opts ./mocha.opts **--env local.example.js**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `mocha` version 6+, you might consider defining configuration in a `*.js` file instead of legacy `*.opts` file.

Then you will be able to run mocha tests with

```sh
$ mocha specs/* --config path/to/config.js
```

More information here: https://mochajs.org/#-config-path